# next command in gdb is not working correctly

Tags: c, gdb

I am simply using gdb to step through a code line by line to learn how it is working and what it is doing. It worked fine the first time I did this, but now the next command is not working right. Sometimes it goes forward, sometimes it goes backwards. It doesn't make sense. Every time I do this it seems to be the same pattern. Below is an example. Anyone know what is wrong?

Note: This is an old Mac with old program versions (That I do not have the power to update)

Please be explicit. I am fairly new to linux and programming in general.

Thanks!

```
Reading symbols for shared libraries ... done
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2730: file ../../../../gcc-3.4.6/libf2c/libF77/pow_zi.c, line 14.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/kevin/project/ConstU/main 
nReading symbols for shared libraries +. done
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1:
Function "main" not defined.
Re-enabling shared library breakpoints: 1

Breakpoint 1, 0x00002730 in main () at main.c:34
34      {
(gdb) n
main () at main.c:42
42      for (i=0;i<DpDIM;i++) {
(gdb) n
34      {
(gdb) n
35      runstart=clock();
(gdb) n
39      Init=ReadInit(&CaseDim);/*reads in initial valies from initfile*/
(gdb) n
35      runstart=clock();
(gdb) n
39      Init=ReadInit(&CaseDim);/*reads in initial valies from initfile*/
(gdb)
```

Comment: What command did you use to compile the program you're stepping through?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to make this more readable, but I think gcc -g -O2?

here is part of the make file:

CC = gcc;      CFLAGS = -g -O2;       main.o : main.c;     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Anyone know what is wrong?

The symptoms you've described are *very* common when debugging programs built with optimization: the compiler re-arranges code in such a way that instructions from different lines become intermixed.

Make sure you compile without any `-O` flags, or add `-O0` at the end of your compilation lines.

> here is part of the make file: `CC = gcc` `CFLAGS = -g -O2`

That would do it: remove `-O2` and your debugging would go much easier.

Comment: It worked. Weird... I looked into that and found this exact line in the manual: " Unlike most other C compilers, GCC allows you to use -g with -O." Thanks!

Comment: GCC *does* allow you to use `-g` and `-O` together, making debugging optimized code possible. But that doesn't make it *easy*.