# GDB is going backwards

Tags: c++, gdb

I am attempting to debug a program with gdb. Here's how I called it, and the commands I gave:

```
> gdb --args program arg1 arg2
(gdb) b program.cpp:251
Breakpoint1 at 0x.... file...., line 251.
(gdb) r
[...] 
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3....
```

I then typed `n` four times, taking me from line 251 to 256. I pressed n again, and ended up on line 251. Subsequent calls took me back to 245, 237, 232, 224, etc.

I am not in a loop on any level whatsoever. How can I make gdb go in the correct direction?

I already tried using `rc`. It says: `Target multi-thread does not support this command.` Same thing with `reverse-next`.

I have tried "turning it off and on again" (restarting gdb).

Here's some context for where the reversal happens. Lot of library code, but I can explain whatever might need clarification.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)             // 163
{
    try
    {
        [...]
        ReadControl reader;                 // 251
        reader.setLogger(logger);
        reader.setRegistry(registry);

        reader.load(testFile, testPaths);   //255
        sharedPointer<Container> container(reader.getContainer());
```

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations off or on? Did you compile with debug info included? What are lines 251-256 (and some surrounding context) in your code?

Comment: @JasonC I'll have to dig into the build system a bit to figure out exactly how this was compiled. Editing main post with code near 256.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159394/next-command-in-gdb-is-not-working-correctly, which I won't flag as a duplicate until you can verify whether or not you've got optimizations enabled and if disabling them solves the issue.

Comment: @JasonC Yeah, this is a dupe, thanks. Almost certain this is compiled with -O3

Comment: Give it a shot with -O0. Should help, in theory. Optimizations nearly always make debugging weird.